# Applying a POSIX date time generator to a data frame

Tags: r, posix

I have a function that creates a random date time in `POSIX` format.

```
rndTime <- function(N, st="2015/01/01", et="2015/12/31"){
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- as.POSIXct(st + ev)
}
```

When I call this into a variable I get a date time like "2015-10-08 15:23:40"  which is exactly the behavior I want.

```
rndday = rndTime(1)
```

However, when I apply this to a data frame I get a num as output.  I have a simple frame midsOver which has two fields, ID (factor) and recnum(char)

```
midsOver$T0 <- sapply(midsOver$recnum, FUN = function(x) rndTime(1), simplify = F)
```

my output is not in `POSIX` date and time format, but is a number such as `1439396281.05214` when the table is viewed.  However looking at the data frame in the global environment T0 is a list of 1 and it shows the `POSIX` format correctly.

I need to see the data format in the data frame.

Thank you

Comment: It helps to add a sample of `midsOver`. It isn't clear if you want to use the default start and end dates or use `recnum` as a start.

Comment: I want to use the default start and end dates in the function.  When I call the apply I use $recnum simply to avoid getting an error by just specifying the frame.

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "T0", value = list(terminal_id = 1431003992.84843,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1

Comment: use `midsOver$T0 <- replicate(nrow(midsOver), rndTime(1))`

Answer (score 0):

The sapply function is converting the POSIX class object back to a numeric.  To convert from numeric back to a time object use either:

```
as.POSIXlt(x, tz = "", origin="1970-01-01")
as.POSIXct(x, tz = "", origin="1970-01-01")
```